# How to solve for $x$ in this equation?: $(1-0.0695)x = 1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve for $x$ this equation?

$$(1-0.0695)x = 1000$$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: How do you solve $2x=3$?

Answer (score 11):

You're only a step away from solving for $x$:

> Given $\quad(1 - 0.0695)x = 1000$

Divide both sides of the equation by $(1 - .0695) = 0.9305$ to obtain $x$:

$$\
\begin{align} (1 - 0.0695)x & = 1000 \\ \\
0.9305\,x & = 1000 \\ \\
x & = \frac{1000}{0.9305} \\
\end{align}
$$

Now just evaluate $x$. You can do so using a calculator or long division, to obtain a decimal approximation, or else represent $x$ precisely as a fraction of integers, reduced so that the numerator and denominator are integers (or $x$ as an integer (the quotient) $+$ (a fraction of integers), the fraction representing the remainder/divisor, reduced).

Added: this problem is no different than one of the form $ax = b,\;$ where $\,x\,$ is the unknown, but $\,a, \,b\,$ are some constants (numbers). To solve, provided $a \neq 0:$ $$ax = b \quad \iff \quad \frac{ax}a = \frac ba \quad \iff \quad x = \dfrac ba$$

Comment: Simple and good+

Answer (score 2):

The numbers suggest that you are expected to come up with a solution that maybe slightly *inexact,* but can be computed *in your head.*
For this note that $\frac1{1-\epsilon}\approx 1+\epsilon$ if $\epsilon$ is small. Here, $0.0695$ may be considered small and hence we can simply approximate $$x\approx 1000\cdot(1+0.0695)=1069.5\approx 1070.$$ Indeed, the true value is only off by about $5$.

Comment: I don't unterstand the downvotes could anyone explain ?

Comment: I don't understand them either.  This seems a very useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You multiply with the inverse of $1-0.0695$ (or just divide it) which is $1.07469$
So you have $$(1-0.0695)x=1000\iff  x= (1-0.0695)^{-1} 1000=1074.69$$

To get an idea where the solution is you could make a plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I don't understand where the numbers on your plot come from.

Comment: The red line is the left hand side, the blue line is the right hand side